# Inserting Array Formula with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, array

I am trying to insert an array formula using VBA but I keep getting the error

**"Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"**

```
Sub Insert()

Range("J2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('Z:\Customer Operations\2021\Tools\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")"

End Sub
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This post does not belong to Super User guidelines, please address your post to Stack Overflow.

Comment: No @LeRouteur VBA and Excel questions belong to both Super User and Stack Overflow.

Comment: the following link may help. https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/long-array-vba-issue.853889/

Comment: Embedded double-quotes must be escaped. If you just put `""`, the resulting string will show `"`. You need to put `""""`

Answer (score 0):

`FormulaArray` property supports maximum length of 255 characters. Your string is too long than the limit.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I changed my formula to the below to get around the 255 characters issue and I still get the same error .... Sub Insert()

Range("J2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C, SMALL(IF(A2='C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$B:$B, ROW('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C)-MIN(ROW('C:\[OrderLinesList.xlsx]Sales'!$C:$C))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")"

End Sub

Comment: @PaulDN edit that update into your question